# How to group in three groups with LINQ for c#

Tags: c#, linq, filter, group-by

I have "Invoice" objects that have a property **Price** . 
Here is my data:

```
Invoice[] arrayOfInvoices = new Invoice[] {     
                new Invoice(83,"Electric Sander",7,57.98m)
            ,   new Invoice(24,"Power Saw",18,99.99m)
            ,   new Invoice(7,"Sledge hammer",11,21.50m)
            ,   new Invoice(77,"Hammer", 76, 11.99m)
            ,   new Invoice(39,"Lawn mower", 3, 79.50m)
            ,   new Invoice(68,"Screwdriver", 106, 6.99m)
            ,   new Invoice(56,"Jig saw", 21, 11.00m)
            ,   new Invoice(3,"Wrench", 34, 7.50m)};
```

I am trying to group invoices in three groups- invoices with Unit price below 10, invoices with unit price
between 10 and 20 and invoices with unit price above of equal to 20. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: Surely it would be easier to just put the commas at the back of the line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the conditional operator to create a switch-like statement:

```
arrayOfInvoices.GroupBy(i => i.Price < 10 ? 0 :
                             i.Price < 20 ? 1 :
                             /*else*/       2)
```

To order within the groups just do an `OrderBy` before you start grouping:

```
arrayOfInvoices.OrderBy(i => i.Price)
               .GroupBy(i => i.Price < 10 ? 0 :
                             i.Price < 20 ? 1 :
                             /*else*/       2)
```

Comment: If I had to add descending or ascending order to the resulted groups how could I do that ?

Comment: Ordering by what?  Price?

Comment: Yes, exactly by price.